# Take ids of text boxes in an html growing table

Tags: html, netbeans, html-table, mysql-workbench

I have made code for auto generated text boxes in an HTML growing table. I want to save values from these text boxes to a mysql database using netbeans but I don't know how I get the ids of each text box while they are auto generating..

My code is here..please help me if there is any solution for this problem..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 24 Mar 2015 06:41:28 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowCount = 1;
function addMoreRows(frm) {
rowCount ++;
var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input name="name" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td><td><input name="email" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td><td><input name="mobile" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td></tr> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');"><img src="./image/close.png" /></a></p>';
jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
}

function removeRow(removeNum) {
jQuery('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <table rules="all" style="background:#fff;">
<tr>
<td style="font-size:14px;" >Name</td>
<td style="font-size:14px;">Email</td>
<td style="font-size:14px;">Mobile</td>
<td><span style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);">
<img style=" padding-left: 12px;"  src="./image/add.png" />
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<form action="" method="POST">
<tr id="rowId">
<td><input type="text" name="name"    size="17%"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile"  /></td>
</form>
</table>
<div id="addedRows"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<td><input type="submit"></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing your html is not proper, you are not using any `form ` tag.
Second as per your code you are not giving any name to all input field also to auto generated fields.  Please first give name to all and then post your form and use name as an index in `$_POST` array.

Comment: You are still not giving any `name` to auto generated text boxes in `addMoreRows` function.

Comment: Dear you are using the same name for auto generated textboxes. Please use different name. Still you have issue in your html, it's not proper, check open and close `table` tag. 

If you want that when i click on add image add a form with three fields name,email,mobile and when i click on submit button save these users in database. Then use `name="name[]"` same as email and mobile then use `foreach` function in `$_POST`.